# Error PHP CodeIgniter Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie

Tags: php

Me sale este error en mi sitio de **PHP** esta montado en **CodeIniter**
ya cheque los controladores que no falten signos o tengan espacio.
Y no se ya por donde buscar estoy usando **PHP 7**

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/lckmx/public_html/application/config/autoload.php:1)
Filename: Session/Session.php
Line Number: 140
Backtrace:
File: /home/lckmx/public_html/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/lckmx/public_html/application/config/autoload.php:1)
Filename: Session/Session.php
Line Number: 140
Backtrace:
File: /home/lckmx/public_html/index.php
Line: 293
Function: require_once
```

Comment: El error indica que algo se ha impreso en la salida justo antes de la llamada `session_start`. Puede ser desde un salto de linea al comiendo de un archivo, hasta algo que se ha enviando usando `echo, print, var_dump, etc.`. Controla bien tu index.php

Comment: Puedes incluir el controlador donde haces el `$this->session->set_userdata($user_data);`

Comment: @lazarok es muy de agradecer que te tomes un tiempo para [sugerir ediciones](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/26686). Sin embargo, sería más útil que te centraras en cosas esenciales como clarificar el texto y eliminar ruido. Poner cursivas no aporta demasiado y está dando trabajo innecesario a los revisores. Si quieres hacer cambios así, gana un poco más de reputación para conseguir el privilegio de [editar preguntas y respuestas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: Te recomiendo poner la parte del codigo donde ocurre el error para que podamos ayudarte mejor

Answer (score 1):

en la carpeta application/config/ existe un archivo llamado autoload en el cual puede cargar librerías como la session esto se realiza de esta forma

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

cualquier cosa estare al tanto, de todas formas mas informacion no esta demás y ayudaría a resolver el problema de forma mas rapida